# Can't access dashboard or plugin page

Tags: php, wordpress

Hello guys I am using wordpress.com (not .org)

Just now I edited a plugin in the editor in dashboard.

There were some errors in the code and my site crashed.

I couldn't log into the dashboard (error 500) and when I go to the plugin page it tells "error fetching plugins".

I guess wordpress.com doesn't support FTP. Then how should I deactivate the error plugin? Thanks for help.